# Дочерний элемент за пределы родительского

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

Доброго времени суток.

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Делаю фиксированное по позиции меню с определенной высотой с несколькими уровнями вложенности. 
Вложенные меню должны выдвигаться в правую сторону.
Как сделать так, чтобы подменю выдвигались без ***расширения зоны родителя*** наружу, при этом была возможность скролла меню в позиции `fixed`.

```css
* {
  transition: .4s;
}

.lvl1,
.lvl2 {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 150px;
}

.lvl1 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /*убрать строку, чтобы увидеть как примерно должно быть*/
  height: 150px;
}

.lvl2 {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: -400px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
}

.lvl1>li:hover .lvl2 {
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="lvl1">
  <li>Hover to here
    <ul class="lvl2">
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>haha</li>
  <li>haha</li>
  <li>haha</li>
  <li>haha</li>
  <li>haha</li>
  <li>haha</li>
  <li>haha</li>
</ul>
```

Песочница :  https://jsfiddle.net/hk2jvL1c/2/

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял - то вам нужно следующее:
1) У родительского li указать position: relative - для того чтобы absolute был относительно его
2) Прописать родительскому li overflow: hidden - тогда не будет появляться полосы прокрутки
3) У lvl2 поставить left: 0 т.к. позиция будет браться относительно родительского li а нужно чтоб меню не вылетало за границы

```css
* {
  transition: .4s;
}
.wrapper{
  height:3000px;
}
.lvl1,
.lvl2 {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.lvl1 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  /*overflow-y: scroll; //убрать строку, чтобы увидеть как примерно должно быть*/
  height: auto;
}

.lvl1 li {
  position: relative;
  /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
}

.lvl2 {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: -400px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
}

.lvl1>li:hover .lvl2 {
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="lvl1">
    <li>Hover to here
      <ul class="lvl2">
        <li>2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>Extra
      <ul class="lvl2">
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
        <li>blah</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>haha</li>
    <li>haha</li>
    <li>haha</li>
    <li>haha</li>
    <li>haha</li>
    <li>haha</li>
    <li>haha</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Кажется вы не совсем меня поняли, если всё уж слишком упростить:
-Меню фиксированное с определенной высотой
-Иметь возможность в меню скролить элементы, которые не вместились в высоту (тут только использовать overflow-y:scroll, или еще что-то можно придумать?)
-При наводке мыши на элементы 1го уровня - в правую сторону выдвигалось меню 2го уровня и его было видно(эту штуку я могу сделать только через позицию fixed, но с такой позицией элемент будет отталкиваться от экрана, а не от родительского элемента - не ок)

Comment: @АртурЕсиопв Сейчас добавил wrapper и назначил ему высоту 3000px для того чтоб его можно было прокручивать - в итоге меню пролистывается и при наведении на пункт меню корректно выскакивает подпункт там где нужно

Comment: а теперь сможете ли вы сделать так, чтобы меню при фиксирвоанной высоте(допустим 120 px) смогло спокойно скроллить n элементов?

Comment: @АртурЕсиопв а тут уже нужно JS скриптом смотреть какую высоту нужно задать, задавать её и прописывать overflow-y: scroll